# Cómo programar una variante de acumulación que no se reinicie al cerrar la aplicación?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy programando un diccionario y la función del historial (Que acumula todo lo previamente buscado) se reinicia cada vez que cierro y abro la aplicación.

la variante **historial** se almacena en una **public static String** que me permite crear una variante de acumulación.

`historial += tv2.getText().toString();`

A su vez esta variante esta guardada en un **SharedPreferences** para que no se borre al cerrar la aplicación.

`SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("datos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`
       `tv2.setText(preferences.getString("favoritos",""));`

Lo que ocurre es que cuando la aplicación se reinicia la variante de acumulación **historial** vuelve a **null** por lo que, si bien el sharedpreferences continúa con con los datos guardados, cuando se ingresa una nueva palabra se sobreescribe el historial y vuelve a cero.

Cómo puedo hacer que siga acumulando en vez de sobreescribir?

Comment: *A su vez esta variante esta relacionada con un SharedPreferences* No sé que quieres decir con "está relacionada". O guardas el valor en el *SharedPreferences* (u otro sistema similar) o no se persistirá. Que calcules el valor en función de **otro valor** que sí está en SharedPreferences no tiene nada que ver.

Comment: @SJuan76 Es verdad estaba mal expresado, ahí lo edite.

Comment: Hola @SantiagoMontagut debe funcionar sin problemas , solo asegura definir el mismo archivo de preferencias "datos" y obtener y guardar con la misma key "favoritos", al guardar no olvides usar el método .apply(); o .commit();

Answer (score 0):

Para poder mantener el valor de tu variable **historial** dentro del tu **Activity**, lo que debes hacer es implementar ademas del guardado, un proceso de recuperación de la misma.

Por defecto, la variable **`historial`** siempre se va a reiniciar a un estado vacío.

Siguiendo el *Lifecycle de un Activity*, te recomiendo implementar la recuperación de la variable en **onCreate** y que utilices el método **onSaveInstanceState** para guardarlo.

La forma de hacerlo sería algo asi:

```
// Aqui obtenemos el valor de la variable previamiente guardado,
// si lo hubiera.
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ...
    // Obtenemos el 
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        CharSequence historial = savedInstanceState.getString("historial");
        tv2.setText(historial);
    }
    // ...
}

// Aqui guardamos el valor de la variable para que esé disponible
// en la proxima ejecución de onCreate.
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //...
    CharSequence historial = tv2.getText();
    outState.putCharSequence("historial", historial ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Todo lo que hay en un programa java se almacena en memoria. Incluidos los datos que nosotros metemos. Estos datos que están en memoria desaparecen al cerrar el programa.

La única solución a mantener los datos de un programa es por medio de medios externos al programa. Bien archivos, bases de datos o demás medios externos de almacenamiento, se acceda como se acceda.

El medio más fácil de conseguir esto es por medio de la escritura y lectura de archivos. Bien por medio de texto, bien por medio de la serialización de objetos (exportación de objetos a archivos). Pero con la serialización hay un peligro, el número de serialización de un programa que no haya sido establecido explícitamente cambia cuando cambia la clase que lo construyó. Por ejemplo, si la clase Persona tiene un campo nombre y se exporta un objeto persona, no podremos cambiar ese campo nombre por nombres. Porque si lo hacemos, seremos incapaces de importar el objeto Persona que habíamos exportado a archivo. Si que podremos hacerlo si hemos establecido un número explícitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de preferencias, crea un método para guardar el valor y uno para obtenerlo. De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

> Lo que ocurre es que cuando la aplicación se reinicia la variante de
>   acumulación historial vuelve a null por lo que, si bien el
>   sharedpreferences continúa con con los datos guardados, cuando se
>   ingresa una nueva palabra se sobreescribe el historial y vuelve a
>   cero.

El problema se puede deber a que no estas guardando correctamente la preferencia, **asegura usar el mismo nombre de archivo de preferencias y la misma KEY al guardar y obtener el valor**:

```
private String PREFS_KEY = "datos";


public void guardaHistorial(Context context, String valor){
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("favoritos", valor);
    editor.apply();
}


public String obtieneHistorial(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getString("favoritos", "");
}
```

De esta forma se guarda y obtiene el valor:

```
//Guarda historial
guardaHistorial(getApplicationContext(), historial);
...
...
...
//Obtiene historial y se agrega a TextView
tv2.setText(obtieneHistorial(getApplicationContext()));
```